# Java/Scala - Reading in from a website that constantly changes

Tags: java, scala, url, io

I have an issue of reading in from a URL which is constantly being modified. This URL is really a current, refreshed view of the DB in some predefined format. Each refresh not only modified the values of each line, but also might generate a completely different order of the lines, which is the most scary bit. Unfortunately the content is too big to be 100% sure that any Reader would actually manage to read in the whole content before the next refresh. On top, usually Buffered reader are used, which only store 2-4kB of data... How would you deal with this problem?

Comment: I am a little confused are you concerned that the response will be corrupted if the page is updated before all the data is transferred back to your program?

Comment: Not really corrupted - just different. upon each page refresh you pretty much get different page...

Comment: If the content of a web page changes while the page is being generated, that web site has some terrible threading issues. So you should be OK, if it works in a browser it will work programmatically from an HTTP client.

Comment: hmm, maybe I did not explain that well enough. The website is generating its content every second. I am trying to read the content but the content can change while I am still reading, due to slow network, server generating data faster than me processing it etc.

Comment: Sure, I understand that, but an http request should be like a transaction, even if the next request 1 second later is different.

Comment: Or @Bober02, do you mean the page grows infinitely? If it's the case keep reading?

Comment: @Bober02, web servers do not work the way you seem to think. Usually they first generate a page and then send it back to the client. It is not possible for a decent web server to change the content of the page while it is already being sent, no matter how the source data of the page has changed.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am reassured now that it should be down to server implementationto send the whole page at once